# Unable to resolve npm install pre-gyp error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, node-pre-gyp

I am trying to install this app locally on my m1 MacBook air >
[Github - Todoist Clone](https://github.com/thepuskar/todoist-clone)

Running npm install in the terminal is causing the following error, please see log below

```
10630 verbose node v16.13.2
10631 verbose npm  v8.1.2
10632 error code 1
10633 error path /Users/Username/Desktop/todoist-clone-master/node_modules/grpc
10634 error command failed
10635 error command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
10636 error CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o
10636 error   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/avl/avl.o
10636 error   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/backoff/backoff.o
10636 error   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channel_args.o
10636 error   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channel_stack.o
10636 error   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channel_stack_builder.o
10636 error   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channel_trace.o
10636 error   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channelz.o
10636 error   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channelz_registry.o
10636 error   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/connected_channel.o
10636 error   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/handshaker.o
10636 error   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/handshaker_registry.o
10636 error   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/status_util.o
10636 error   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/compression/compression.o
10636 error   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/compression/compression_args.o
10636 error   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/compression/compression_internal.o
10636 error   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/compression/message_compress.o
10636 error   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/compression/stream_compression.o
10636 error   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/compression/stream_compression_gzip.o
10636 error   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/compression/stream_compression_identity.o
10636 error   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/debug/stats.o
10636 error   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/debug/stats_data.o
10636 error Failed to execute '/Users/Username/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/bin/node /Users/Username/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/Users/Username/Desktop/todoist-clone-master/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v93-darwin-arm64-unknown/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/Users/Username/Desktop/todoist-clone-master/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v93-darwin-arm64-unknown --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
10637 error node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
10637 error node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.13.0
10637 error node-pre-gyp info using node@16.13.2 | darwin | arm64
10637 error node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
10637 error node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/Users/Username/Desktop/todoist-clone-master/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v93-darwin-arm64-unknown/grpc_node.node" (not found)
10637 error node-pre-gyp http GET https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.23.3/node-v93-darwin-arm64-unknown.tar.gz
10637 error node-pre-gyp http 404 https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.23.3/node-v93-darwin-arm64-unknown.tar.gz
10637 error node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.23.3/node-v93-darwin-arm64-unknown.tar.gz
10637 error node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.23.3 and node@16.13.2 (node-v93 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
10637 error node-pre-gyp http 404 status code downloading tarball https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.23.3/node-v93-darwin-arm64-unknown.tar.gz
10637 error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
10637 error gyp info using node-gyp@8.3.0
10637 error gyp info using node@16.13.2 | darwin | arm64
10637 error gyp info ok
10637 error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
10637 error gyp info using node-gyp@8.3.0
10637 error gyp info using node@16.13.2 | darwin | arm64
10637 error gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.9 found at "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3"
10637 error gyp info spawn /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3
10637 error gyp info spawn args [
10637 error gyp info spawn args   '/Users/Username/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
10637 error gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
10637 error gyp info spawn args   '-f',
10637 error gyp info spawn args   'make',
10637 error gyp info spawn args   '-I',
10637 error gyp info spawn args   '/Users/Username/Desktop/todoist-clone-master/node_modules/grpc/build/config.gypi',
10637 error gyp info spawn args   '-I',
10637 error gyp info spawn args   '/Users/Username/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
10637 error gyp info spawn args   '-I',
10637 error gyp info spawn args   '/Users/Username/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.13.2/include/node/common.gypi',
10637 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
10637 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
10637 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/Username/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.13.2',
10637 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/Username/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
10637 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/Username/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.13.2/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
10637 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/Username/Desktop/todoist-clone-master/node_modules/grpc',
10637 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
10637 error gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
10637 error gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
10637 error gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
10637 error gyp info spawn args   'build',
10637 error gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
10637 error gyp info spawn args ]
10637 error gyp info ok
10637 error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
10637 error gyp info using node-gyp@8.3.0
10637 error gyp info using node@16.13.2 | darwin | arm64
10637 error gyp info spawn make
10637 error gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
10637 error ../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/debug/stats_data.cc:284:5: error: suspicious concatenation of string literals in an array initialization; did you mean to separate the elements with a comma? [-Werror,-Wstring-concatenation]
10637 error     "requested the incoming call",
10637 error     ^
10637 error ../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/debug/stats_data.cc:283:5: note: place parentheses around the string literal to silence warning
10637 error     "How many completion queues were checked looking for a CQ that had "
10637 error     ^
10637 error 1 error generated.
10637 error make: *** [Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/debug/stats_data.o] Error 1
10637 error gyp ERR! build error
10637 error gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
10637 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/Username/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
10637 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
10637 error gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
10637 error gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.2.0
10637 error gyp ERR! command "/Users/Username/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/bin/node" "/Users/Username/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=/Users/Username/Desktop/todoist-clone-master/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v93-darwin-arm64-unknown/grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=/Users/Username/Desktop/todoist-clone-master/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v93-darwin-arm64-unknown" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v93"
10637 error gyp ERR! cwd /Users/Username/Desktop/todoist-clone-master/node_modules/grpc
10637 error gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.2
10637 error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.3.0
10637 error gyp ERR! not ok
10637 error node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
10637 error node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/Users/Username/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/bin/node /Users/Username/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/Users/Username/Desktop/todoist-clone-master/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v93-darwin-arm64-unknown/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/Users/Username/Desktop/todoist-clone-master/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v93-darwin-arm64-unknown --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
10637 error node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/Username/Desktop/todoist-clone-master/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
10637 error node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
10637 error node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
10637 error node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
10637 error node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.2.0
10637 error node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/Users/Username/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/bin/node" "/Users/Username/Desktop/todoist-clone-master/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
10637 error node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/Username/Desktop/todoist-clone-master/node_modules/grpc
10637 error node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.2
10637 error node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.13.0
10637 error node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
10638 verbose exit 1
```

I tried following steps from posts with similar pre-gyp-err issues but none worked

If anyone is able to resolve it, please advise the steps I need to follow

Comment: Did you ever manage to resolve this? I am having the same issue on an M1 MacBook Pro. Same Node, node-gyp and node-pre-gyp versions, and the devDependency answer below doesn't fix it for me.

Comment: @JamesHooper did you solve it?

Comment: Hi Bilal, I did. I managed to get the repo working, as well as my own project. I've posted an answer below, along with a fork of the repo that you can clone and run without issue :)

Comment: It's because of the angular version not supporting the firebase. Hence update the firebase which probably might be on v5. Do update it to v7 or v8.

Answer (score 5):

**This was bothering me a lot in my own project, but I think I've figured it out. It seems that it is actually an obscure problem that is created by the `firebase` and `node-sass` versions you're using.**

Firebase versions below 7 depend on `grpc` [which has been deprecated](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/1880#issuecomment-897147496) in favour of `@grpc/grpc-js`. This can be fixed by upgrading to version 7 or higher.

Similarly, the `node-sass` package [has been deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass). The NPM package says to use [`dart-sass`](https://sass-lang.com/dart-sass), but in the project you linked, it was simple to run the single `.scss` file through a compiler and change it to basic CSS.

[Here's a fork of the project with the dependencies fixed.](https://github.com/FitFingers/todoist-clone-m1-fix/tree/fix/m1-fix)
I removed the `firebase` package (I left the `firebase` code still in there but commented it out for reference / re-adding) and `node-sass` was also removed. It should now be possible to simply clone the repo and run `npm i` to install (tested with node 16), and it should load in the browser too. The only thing left to do is to reimplement the `firebase` code so that it works with version 7 (previously it used 5).

Comment: Thanks awesome dude! I was having trouble for firebase library which I am not using.